# Use lists to get objects in dictionary but not as keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I was a bit surprised when I tried to do

```
if list in dict:
```

and got

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I know it does not make sense to use lists as keys as they are mutable and their hash could change when you do operations on them. However, why is it not possible to use them to simply look up objects in a dictionary? I know it is not much work doing

```
if tuple(list) in dict:
```

rather than just

```
if list in dict:
```

But still, I feel like it would work as default behavior as the hash of its current elements should be the exact same thing as the hash of the corresponding tuple that may be in the dictionary? Or am I missing something in what makes lists unusable in dictionaries?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can calculate hash of a `list` (as any other sequence of bits) and implement desired behavior.

Hovewer,

- `tuple`s are immutable objects, hash of a `tuple` may be calculated **once**, at initialization
- `list`s are mutable. They may change its state and hashing based on elements of a `list` will produce different hashes, if state was changed. So, using this hashing method, hash of `list` can't be precalculated

Now consider `in` operation.

When you check `a_tuple in a_dict`, hash of `a_tuple` is known, and `in` operation takes linear time `O(len(a_dict))`.

Suppose, that someone implemented `a_list in a_dict` operation. This would take `O(len(a_list))` + `O(len(a_dict))` time, because you have to calculate hash of `a_list`. Therefore, unintended behavior happens.

On other hand, if we consider another hashing method that takes O(1), e.g. just by link to an object. You will get another behavior of `a_list in a_dict`. Because if `a_list == b_list` and `not a_list is b_list`, then `(a_list in a_dict) != (b_list in a_dict)`.

Also, [notice](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) that

> Tuples can be used as keys if they contain only strings, numbers, or tuples

Comment: I know you can calculate the hash and that's why I wondered why python didn't want to. I don't really see how there can be a time difference as the tuple can be defined using a variable in it and the hash would have to be calculated after its creation anyway but yes it would only be once if you ever reuse the tuple. Of course you can define it differently but for python implementation I thought it would work right out of the bat for lists

Comment: @Water Also, consider behavior of get operation on `dict` with a `list` as a key. While `a_list is a_list` whenever `a_list` is changed or not, operation `a_dict[a_list]` before and after changes in `a_list` must be clarified.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't think "why does Python work like that" questions are on-topic for this site, I'm gonna say this seems like a terrible idea. You are not supposed to (cannot) use lists as keys in a dictionary, so why would you expect them to be among the keys? If you are looking for a tuple, why would
you want to pass a list instead?

Comment: Sorry I browse sometimes but am never active here so I didn't realize it was off-topic. Well just because you can calculate the hash value in exactly the same way and because I think it would work. A lot of time in python if you can do things just because they work and python being loosely typed it doesn't seem like a big deal to use lists this way.

Comment: It's not "exactly the same way" You are calulating hash of a tuple, which represents single specific state of the list. Python is loosely typed, so anything that supports a specific function will work wherever that function is needed. Lists do not support hashing.

Comment: It's like trying to do `if 1 in "123"` It doesn't work, because `1 != '1'`, even though `str(1) == '1'`. As the Python Zen says: **"Explicit is better than implicit"**

Comment: That's what I mean, whatever function calculates the hash, say h(tuple), would give the exact same result for a list containing the same elements as the tuple for the function h(list). So since python is loosely typed that's why I thought it would allow it. A list represents at any line where it is not modified a single specific state of a list, just like a tuple.

Comment: The thing is Python does not implement a hashing function for lists. At all. You can check that `(1,2).__hash__()` will give you some output, but `[1,2].__hash__()` throws an error because no such thing is implemented. You can create your own subclass that inherits from `list` and implements `__hash__` and it will work will all the mentioned stuff, but by default `list` doesn't have it because, frankly - hashing doesn't make much sense for mutable objects.

Comment: Yes but for convenience sake I thought maybe it would be nice to have but only when looking up keys, not defining them as that would as you said not make sense. This use case does not seem so bad to me. To me this would just be a nice to have which python has a lot of so I don't see why not. Also you can define mutable classes with changing hashes so it's not like python have barred the behavior it just doesn't implement it itself.